# How can I group a multidimensional array by a specific key of its inner arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
$my_array = array(
    array(
        array('cnt' => 1, 'date' => '2016-06-18', 'name' => 'Phone Calls'),
        array('cnt' => 1,'date' => '2016-06-18','name' => 'Others Works')
    ),
    array(
        array('cnt' => 2 , 'date' => '2016-06-17', 'name' => 'Phone Calls'),
        array('cnt' => 1, 'date' => '2016-06-17', 'name' => 'Others Works')
    )
);
```

which I need to convert into the format below to accomplish my specific purpose.

```
$desired_result = array(
    array('name' => 'Phone Calls', 'dateDetail' => array(
        array('cnt' => 1, 'date' => '2016-06-18'),
        array('cnt' => 2, 'date' => '2016-06-17'),
    )),
    array('name' => 'Others Works', 'dateDetail' => array(
        array('cnt' => 1, 'date' => '2016-06-18'),
        array('cnt' => 1, 'date' => '2016-06-17'),        
    ))
);
```

I need to group my array by name with all date and count data together inside. Can someone please help me to format this array?

Comment: i need to draw d3chart where i need to convert my array format.What i want to try is http://jsfiddle.net/JYS8n/1/

Comment: nope i am not getting any error.First array is array what i have now and i need to convert array format for my chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by name by popping off the name from each of the lowest level arrays and using it as a higher-level key for the reorganized array.

```
foreach ($your_array as $day) {
    foreach ($day as $item) {
        $name = array_pop($item);                  // removes the 'name' key and returns it
        $converted[$name]['name'] = $name;
        $converted[$name]['dateDetail'][] = $item;
    }
}

$result = array_values($converted);                // convert from string keys to numeric
```

`array_pop` only happens to work because `name` is the last key in the item arrays. If it wasn't, you would need to specify which key to remove and use like this:

```
$name = $item['name'];
unset($item['name']);
```

---

To add grouping by `date` within the `dateDetail` array for each `name`, the idea is the same as when grouping by name. Use `date` as a key within `dateDetail`, and add to the `cnt` key for repeated date values.

```
foreach ($your_array as $day) {
    foreach ($day as $item) {
        $name = array_pop($item);
        $new[$name]['name'] = $name;

        // check if the date is already set
        if (isset($new[$name]['dateDetail'][$item['date']])) {
            // if so, add the count of the current item
            $new[$name]['dateDetail'][$item['date']]['cnt'] += $item['cnt'];
        } else {
            // if not, set it.
            $new[$name]['dateDetail'][$item['date']] = $item;
        }
    }
}

// remove the date string keys
foreach ($new as &$name) {
    $name['dateDetail'] = array_values($name['dateDetail']);
}
unset($name);    // unset the reference

// remove the name string keys
$result = array_values($new);
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have an array with key name. But i need to add cnt key values having same date too.Can you please explain me how can i do this?

Comment: The principle would be the same as grouping by name. Use date as an additional key within `dateDetail` and increment it for each item with a matching date.

Comment: @MadAdh I updated the answer with an example to show what I meant.

Comment: Thanks, @Fred-ii-.